# Small font size in blog page's footer

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, design, blog

In the footer of the [blog page](https://stackoverflow.blog/), the font of the social media links and copyright section is very small compared with all other Stack Exchange site's footer font.

[image: Small font in blog page]

Comment: I think this is intentional, and not a bug. This is true for every SE site, including SO itself, not just exclusive to the blog site.

Comment: [Feeling like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfzsv.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The footer on the blog is designed to mirror the footer on stackoverflow.com. In both cases, the copyright and social media links are 11px, which is smaller than the other links in the footer.  However, it the blog makes the *other* footer links 16px instead of the 13px that the main site uses, making it seem like the smaller text is even smaller relative to the other text in the footer.

I'll get that fixed so they are the same size (reducing the size of the footer links on the blog).

Answer (score 1):

If you look around the internet, you will see this is very common. Terms and conditions need to be accessible, but they aren't as likely to be visited as the other links in that footer. The vast majority of visitors want to quickly and easily get to the SE site they are interested in.

Those who want to read the T&C's will know to find the link and follow it.

Similarly with the copyright notice. You don't want it to detract from the site, but you want it to be there.

Comment: True but the issue here is that it's small **compared to other sites in SE itself**.

Comment: Is it? It looks almost the same on every site for me.

Comment: Yes, maybe seeing it together will help: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3w47.png (the font size in the blog is about 80% of the font size on all other sites due to some CSS rule)

Comment: That's interesting. I have them at the same size and style on every site. I don't do any clever CSS stuff so it must be a default setting somewhere.

Comment: The diff is only between the sites and the blog, you sure you look in the [blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/)?

Comment: Yep. I followed the same link

Comment: So this is really weird.